# Wiring 2 separate PIR’s to an LED Floodlight

Tags: lighting, pir

If possible can someone please confirm that this would work?

I want to place a waterproof box on the front of the house, next to this I will put an LED floodlight (without PIR), I then want to put 1 PIR about 10 meters away from the house in one direction, and then another PIR 50 meters away in another direction, would the quick note I made below work or have I got it wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated.

James

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks about right. You are paralleling the motion sensors, and connecting the light to the combined switched output (L' on your diagram) of the motion sensor. If either gets triggered, then the light will turn on.

See this DIY question for some more info. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80490/multiple-motion-detectors-wired-together

Comment: Thanks for that, just wanted to make sure, cheers...